Computing asteroid positions and getting to Earth Interial Frame
I am currently working on a "planetarium"-like VRChat world, and I've been able to use the TLE data for satellites along with a port of the SGP4 algorithm I made, as a single-file-header in generic C, here https://github.com/cnlohr/csgp4 - and crucially with single-precision floating point only (because the computations have to run in geometry shaders).
I believe I'm already working in the TEME coordinate frame, since that seems to be what SGP4's output is in.
I am hoping to add planets, and asteroids, for instance, those outlined in the database here: https://asteroid.lowell.edu/astorb/.
And, as part of that, I hope to also build and publish a single-file-header that can do this computation as well.  I understand that it's going to be difficult to make it reasonable with single-precision floating point, but so far many of the orbital libraries for planets I am finding would just absolutely crumple up if I had to port them to something with single-precision.
Mostly, I am just struggling to understand how to:
Compute asteroids and planets in a coordinate frame that is easily transferable TEME without using large existing libraries because I have to port to a geometry shader.
